# vue.js no data rendering

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to go through a basic vue tutorial. Recently I must have changed something that is stopping anything in the vue.js from rendering on my page and I can't seem to find out why. Example: instead of displaying the value of data.product, it displays `{{ Product }}`. Thanks in advance for any help!
Here's a link to the project repo on gitlab: [project link](https://gitlab.com/KayDeeJay/vue-mastery-tutorial)

Comment: Hey there! I think you could improve this question by trying to provide any error messages from the dev tools, and maybe setup a codepen or something similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you will see an `Uncaught ReferenceError` if you open the DevTools of your browser. Because in your `main.js` file you reference two times to non-existent variables. In your `variants-array` you are using `Green` and `Blue` for your `variantColor` as variables but non of them is defined. From context I guess you just want to display these two values as string at your page, so you have to assign a string to your `variantColor` variable by adding single or double quotes.

Inside your `main.js` change your variant array to this:

```
...
variants: [
 {
   variantId: 2234,
   variantColor: 'Green'
 },
 {
   variantId: 2235,
   variantColor: 'Blue'
 }
]
...
```